# error about invoking MatLab function from java

Tags: java, matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I'm using MatLab2013a 64bit and Java7. What I'm trying to do is that invokes a matlab function from Java by javabuilder,I create a matlab project to compile the function,the following is my matlab function

```
function SP=imagerotate(filename,theta)
    I=imread(filename);
    SP=imrotate(I,theta);
```

and then I add it to a class named `RotateImage`(this is the common procedure to compile Matlab function). And there is no error happened.then I create a Java Project and add `distrib\flying.jar` and `C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v81\toolbox\javabuilder\jar\javabuilder.jar`. when I try to test it,there is an error happened.

package image;

```
import com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.MWClassID;
import com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.MWNumericArray;
import flying.RotateImage;

/**
 * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: ssj-at-work
 * Date: 13-9-22
 * Time: 上午11:00
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Begin");
            RotateImage flyingDraw = new RotateImage();
            System.out.println("Middle");
            MWNumericArray theta = new MWNumericArray(90, MWClassID.INT16);
            String filename=new String("C:\\Users\\ssj-at-work\\Desktop\\Picture\\GN20130625_1.jpg");
            Object img[]=null;
            img=flyingDraw.imagerotate(1,filename,theta);
            int[] k=((MWNumericArray) img[0]).getDimensions();
            for (int i:k){
                System.out.println(i);
            }
            System.out.println("Here");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

the error message is as following

```
Invalid MEX-file 'F:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\mcr\toolbox\matlab\imagesci\private\rjpg8c.mexw64': 找不到指定的模块。

Error in readjpg (line 12)



Error in imread (line 416)



Error in imagerotate (line 2)



Unable to print provided exception.

Caused by:
    Errors occurred while loading the Settings files. 
    Details: F:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\toolbox\matlab\matlab.settings  Internal Error: Failed to find SAX plugin.
    C:\Users\SSJ-AT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ssj-at-work\mcrCache8.1\flying0\.matlab\matlab.settings    Internal Error: Failed to find SAX plugin.
    There is no Settings files associated with this product node: matlab. The Settings files may be deleted after MATLAB started up. Please restart MATLAB to fully solve this issue.
    .


Process finished with exit code 255
```

please help me out.

Comment: this might be unrelated but try to use Java 6 instead.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that \v81\bin\win64 corresponding to MCR 8.1 is ahead in system PATH
   environment variable than the one corresponding to MCR 8.0.
2. The workaround is to add the following entry to system PATH explicitly:
   \v81\bin\win64